# Identifying points based on spatial proximity to other points in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, point, proximity

I have two shapefiles. One has location of around 10,000 buildings and the other has location of around 8000 parking lots. I want to identify which parking lot is closest to the building based on spatial proximity and also the distance between the identified parking lot and the building in separate fields.
I am using ArcMap.

Can you help me?
[image]

Comment: If you wish to also ask about QGIS or ArcGIS Pro then please do that in a separate question.

Comment: Isn't near analysis (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/near.htm) exactly for this?